# jQueryUI Resizable alsoResize can't be passed $(this).next()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When using jQueryUI `.resizable()` function, I'm trying to cause the next element in the DOM to also be resized.  I can pass a jQuery selector, or even a string with a class or ID to the `alsoResize` method, but I can't pass `$(this).next()` to select the next element in DOM.

My code:

`$(selector).resizable({ alsoResize:$(this).next() });`

You can run the fiddle here, and uncomment the lines 67/68 to see this work/not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/WpgzZ/706/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `this` is referring to the document (you can see this by doing `console.log(this)`). If you change it to `alsoResizeReverse: $("#resizable").next()` it should work for you.

**Edit**

You can do something like this:

```
$.each($("#colors li"), function(index, value) {
  $(this).resizable({ alsoResize:$(this).next() })
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit out of the context of my app in the jsfiddle -- in my actual application there are many `<div>`s, not just ONE next element.  So, the `.next()` can't be called on a specific ID.  The reason I am calling `$(this).next()` is because I am trying to refer to `$(this)` as the element that `.resizable()` is being called on.  Am I incorrectly referencing `$(this)` as the element `.resizable()` is being called on?

Comment: So what would that section of code generally look like in your app?

Comment: `$("#colors li").resizable({ alsoResize:$("#colors li").next() })` -- remember there are multiple `<li>` elements nested under `#colors`

Answer (score 0):

It is because when the code is executed `this` is not pointed to the "#resizable" element

```
$("#resizable").resizable({
    alsoResizeReverse: $("#resizable").next(),
    // alsoResizeReverse: $(".myframe"),
});
```